# Laravel 5 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the follwing routs defined in routs.php:

```
Route::get('/',"TodoListController@index" );

Route::get('/todos',"TodoListController@index" );

Route::resource('/', 'TodoListController');
```

but only the first one work. I use xampp to develop my Laravel app.
This is the url that work:
http://localhost/restapp/public/
and that don't work:http://localhost/restapp/public/todos

Thanks for help

Comment: I guess its an issue of .htaccess

Comment: To remove `public` from your URL add `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>` to your .htaccess

Comment: I don't use .htaccess for this project.

Comment: you can create one since you are using xampp or you can forget xampp and try `php artisan serve`

Comment: Thanks if i use php artisan serve it works.

Comment: Okay. I moved this to answer. You may accept or wait for other answers if you wish

Answer (score 1):

To remove public from your URL add

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 
    public/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

to your .htaccess

or You can forget XAMPP and use:

```
php artisan serve
```